# Subaggregation leads to missing data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Question in short**: When executing a query with a subaggregation, why does the inner aggregation miss data in some cases?

**Question in detail**: I have a search query with a subaggregation (buckets in buckets) as follows:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "outer_docs": {
            "terms": {"size": 20, "field": "field_1_to_aggregate_on"},
            "aggs": {
                "inner_docs": {
                    "terms": {"size": 10000, "field": "field_2_to_aggregate_on"},
                    "aggs": "things to display here"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute this query, for some outer_docs, I receive not all inner_docs that are associated with it. In the output below, there are three inner docs for outer doc key_1.

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 9853,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "outer_docs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1, "sum_other_doc_count": 9801,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "key_1", "doc_count": 3,
                    "inner_docs": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {"key": "1", "doc_count": 1, "some": "data here"},
                            ...
                            {"key": "3", "doc_count": 1, "some": "data here"},
                        ]
                    }
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I add a query to singly select one outer_doc that would have been in the first 20 anyway.

```
"query": {"bool": {"must": [{'term': {'field_1_to_aggregate_on': 'key_1'}}]}}
```

In this case, I do get all inner_docs, which are in the output below seven inner docs for outer doc key_1.

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 8,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "outer_docs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1, "sum_other_doc_count": 9801,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "key_1", "doc_count": 8,
                    "inner_docs": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {"key": "1", "doc_count": 1, "some": "data here"},
                            ...
                            {"key": "7", "doc_count": 2, "some": "data here"},
                        ]
                    }
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have specified explicitly that I want 10,000 inner_docs per outer_doc. What is preventing me from getting all data?

This is my version information:

```
{
    'build_date': '2018-09-26T13:34:09.098244Z',
    'build_flavor': 'default',
    'build_hash': '04711c2',
    'build_snapshot': False,
    'build_type': 'deb',
    'lucene_version': '7.4.0',
    'minimum_index_compatibility_version': '5.0.0',
    'minimum_wire_compatibility_version': '5.6.0',
    'number': '6.4.2'
}
```

**EDIT**: After digging a bit more, I found out that the issue was unrelated to subaggregation, but to aggregation itself and the usage of shards. I have opened this bug report for Elastic about it:

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bug-in-aggregation-result-when-using-shards/164161
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/37425

Comment: `"sum_other_doc_count": 9801` is an indication here. May I ask how many `inner_docs` buckets show up for each of the `outer_docs` ones?

Comment: What does it indicate? I don't find it a high number to be honest. Per outer_doc, there should be between 5 and 10 inner_docs available. The problem is that we don't see all of those 5 to 10.

Comment: These results are indeed strange. I can't replicate it on 6.3.2 with a slightly bigger data size. What are the types of fields for field_1_to_aggregate_on and field_2_to_aggregate_on?

Comment: What happens if you run `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"persistent": {"search.max_buckets": 30000}}'` ?

Comment: @BrianOlsen: They are both strings.

Comment: @Val: The max buckets settings is changed, but we still get the same results. Note that it is not a problem of reaching a limit for buckets. We have 20 outer buckets, each with less than 10 inner buckets. We also don't hit any document limit, we don't even have 10,000 documents.

Comment: Yes, but those 20 outer buckets don't seem to account for all documents. What do you see if you increase the outer bucket count to, say 50? Do you see `sum_other_doc_count` decrease?

Comment: Indeed when increasing the number of outer buckets, the results of the first 20 buckets were more accurate. We now learned that this inaccuracy is a feature of ElasticSearch, which I have elaborated on a bit more in the Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not due to subaggregation, and that it is an actual feature of ElasticSearch. We are using 5 shards, and when using shards, aggregations only return approximate results.

We have made this problem reproducible, and posted it in the [Elastic discuss forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bug-in-aggregation-result-when-using-shards/164161). There, we learned that aggregations do not always return all data, with a link to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts) where this is explained in more detail.

We also learned that using only 1 shard solves the issue, and when that is not possible, the parameter `shard_size` can alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check your elastic deprecation logfile. You will probably have some warnings like this:

```
This aggregation creates too many buckets (10001) and will throw an error in future versions. You should update the [search.max_buckets] cluster setting or use the [composite] aggregation to paginate all buckets in multiple requests.
```

search.max_buckets is a dynamic cluster setting that defaults to 10.000 buckets in 7.0.

Now, this is not documented anywhere, but in my experience: Allocating over 10.000 buckets result in the termination of your query, but you will get back the results that have been achieved until that moment. This explains missing data in your result

Using the composite Aggregation will help, your other option is to increase the max_buckets. Be careful with that, you can crash your entire cluster that way, because there is a cost for every bucket (RAM). It does not matter if you actually use all the allocated buckets, you can crash with empty buckets only.

See:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_literal_search_max_buckets_literal_in_the_cluster_setting
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/35896

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Note that my problem is not that I have too many buckets. I have 20 outer buckets, each of which contains less than 10 inner buckets.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) for this? Pretty sure that solves your problem.

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "all_docs": {
            "composite" : {
                "size": 1000,
                "sources" : [
                    { "outer_docs": { "terms": { "field": "field_1_to_aggregate_on" } } },
                    { "inner_docs": { "terms": { "field": "field_2_to_aggregate_on" } } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have many buckets, the composite aggregation will help you scroll through each of them using [`size`/`after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_size).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I see two reasons why this solution is not ideal. The first is that I have to post-process the data in the program calling ElasticSearch to build in the hierarchy. A second, more important reason is that I need the outer buckets to be ordered by an aggregation on that entire bucket, not on a composite value of outer_doc and inner_doc. The ordering is important, since I only return the top 20 buckets.