# How to mention from and size for the first level of elastic search aggregation in nested aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a query to get the buckets based on id and then sort it. This works fine. But how to make it return buckets from position 100 till 200 for aggregation_by_id rule?

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
        "aggregation_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id.keyword"
                "size" : 200
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sort_timestamp": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{
                            "timestamp": {
                            "order": "desc",
                            "unmapped_type": "long"
                            }
                        }],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148252/4604579 (hint: use composite aggregation)

Comment: Composite aggregation will return "after_key" which can be used to fetch next set of values. However, my question is can i directly ask it to return from 100th position till 200th bucket?

Comment: I got that, but that answer is still no :-)

Comment: Ok so i will not be able to make it return from 100th to 200th bucket. Thank you

Comment: ...unless you ignore the query that returns buckets 0 to 100